# uml class diagram for boxing match

Tags: class, uml, relationship

I am working on a uml class diagram. I want to know what is the relation between rematch class and match class for a boxing game. Is it inheritance or association?

Rematch happens when there is a tie in the match. But, rematch also has "is a" relation with match.

Answer (score 2):

In short, both inheritance and association.
Inheritance - «rematch also has "is a" relation with match».
Association - «Rematch happens when there is a tie in the match»